# Perl HTTPS server using HTTP::Daemon and Crypt-SSLeay

Tags: perl, https

How can I create an HTTPS daemon?

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you having problems? And another important question: Why do you want to do it? Give us more information please.

Comment: Sorry for a very short question. I am using ActiveState Perl. I need to create a lightweight HTTP over SSL server using HTTP::Daemon and some SSL package. As I understand IO::Socket::SSL is not supported by ActiveState Perl so I am looking forward for an solution using Crypt-SSLeay package. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [HTTP::Daemon::App](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aDaemon%3a%3aApp), or the [status of HTTPS in Plack Web servers](http://groups.google.com/group/psgi-plack/browse_thread/thread/999868303b483ba2).

Putting a SSL-capable reverse proxy, such as Apache httpd, nginx, Perlbal, in front of the app server is always an option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I can not use HTTP::Daemon::App. This package calls the HTTP::Daemon::SSL for SSL which in turn use the IO::Socket::SSL package. This differ for me as I can not use IO::Socket::SSL package. I am looking forward to have HTTP SSL using Crypt-SSLeay. It seems that IO::Socket::SSL is not supported by Activate State PPM.